# Statistics problem (normal distribution)

Tags: calculus, statistics, multivariable-calculus

A factory produces roller stands (of cylindrical form) that has $4cm$. of diameter and $6cm$. of length. In fact, the diameters $X$ are normally distributed with a mean of $4cm$. and a standard desviation of $0,01cm$, being its density $f_{1}(x)$. By the way, the lengths $Y$ are normally distributed, with a mean of $6cm$. and a standard desviation of $0,01cm$, whose density is $f_{2}(y)$.
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, i.e., $f(x,y)=f_{1}(x)f_{2}(y)$, find the probability that the length and the diameter of a stand randomly chosen at the line of production differ from their respective mean over $0.02cm$.

Well, $X$ and $Y$ are probability density function, so we need to use $$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! \left\{ 1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{\sigma\,
\sqrt {\pi }}} \right\} {{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{\frac { \left( x-\mu \right) 
^{2}}{{\sigma}^{2}}}}}{dx}=1
$$

But I haven't much knowledge about statistics. (Sorry if I make a mistake writing the exercise, I speak spanish). If anyone can explain me I would really apreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability of Diameter $D\in (x,x+dx)=P(x<D<x+dx)=f_1(x)dx$

Therefore, $P(4-0.02<D<4+0.02)=\int_{4-0.02}^{4+0.02}f_1(x)dx$ and similarly, $P(6-0.02<L<6+0.02)=\int_{6-0.02}^{6+0.02}f_2(y)dy$

As $D,L$ are independent, therefore, $P(4-0.02<D<4+0.02,6-0.02<L<6+0.02)=\left(\int_{4-0.02}^{4+0.02}f_1(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{6-0.02}^{6+0.02}f_2(y)dy\right)$

As $f_1,f_2$ are pdf's of normal dist. and their cdf's denoted by $\Phi$ for their standard forms, hence $\int_{4-0.02}^{4+0.02}f_1(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{4+0.02}f_1(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^{4-0.02}f_1(x)dx=\Phi(\frac{4.02-4}{0.01})-\Phi(\frac{3.98-4}{0.01})$

Comment: You forgot to subract off the mean in the last line.  The probability that normal random variable $X$ differs its mean $\mu = 4$ by at most $2$ standard deviations is quite high ($\Phi(2)-\Phi(-2)$, in fact) and not the small value $\Phi(4.02)-\Phi(3.98)$ that you get.

Answer (score 2):

You need to evaluate the following expression:

$P((4-0.02 \le X \le 4+0.02) \cap  (6-0.02 \le  Y \le 6+0.02))$

Now, use the following facts:

1. If two events, $A, B$ are independent then $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$
2. If $Z \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $P(-a \le Z \le b) = \Phi(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}) - \Phi(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma})$ where $\Phi(.)$ is the cdf of a normal with mean $0$ and variance $1$.